# trigger doesn't work on load

Tags: jquery, triggers

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("1");
    $('#selectid').triggerHandler('change');
    $('#selectid').trigger('change');
    $('#selectid').change();
    console.log("2");
    $('#intervention1-form').change(function() {
        console.log('WHY DOESNT THIS HAPPEN?');
  });
});
console.log("0");
```

Console output should be:

```
0
1
WHY DOESNT THIS HAPPEN?
2
```

But instead, it's just:

```
0
1
2
```

The context is that I am populating an HTML element with different stuff when a select menu (selectid) is changed. However, when the page first loads, I want to trigger the select menu as if it is changed, so that the HTML element has content even if the user doesn't change the select menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you attach a change handler with your console log in it, after you already triggered the change.

so you will catch only change events that happen from the moment you bind your change handler, not the ones that happened before that

changing up your code to this would solve the issue:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#intervention1-form').change(function() {
        console.log('WHY DOESNT THIS HAPPEN?');
    });
    console.log("1");
    $('#selectid').triggerHandler('change');
    $('#selectid').trigger('change');
    $('#selectid').change();
    console.log("2");
});
console.log("0");
```

now you have the output you desire, because you bound the change handler before triggering it.

Comment: not to be ungrateful, but honestly for the sake of this community and helping others with similar problems i vote to make ShankarSangoli's answer the correct one. His was first and is way better explained than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are attaching the click handler afterwards. `trigger("change")` executes all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the `change` event. If there is no handler attached then there is nothing to execute.

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("1");
    $('#intervention1-form').change(function() {
        console.log('WHY DOESNT THIS HAPPEN?');
    });
    $('#selectid').change();
    console.log("2");
});
console.log("2");
```

Side Note: Calling `trigger("change")` or `change()` method is one and the same.

> The .triggerHandler() method behaves similarly to .trigger(), with the
>   following exceptions:
>
> - The .triggerHandler() method does not cause the default behavior of    an event to occur (such as a form submission).
> - While .trigger() will operate on all elements matched by the jQuery    object, .triggerHandler() only affects the first matched element.
> - Events created with .triggerHandler() do not bubble up the DOM    hierarchy; if they are not handled by the target element directly,
>     they do nothing.
> - Instead of returning the jQuery object (to allow chaining),    .triggerHandler() returns whatever value was returned by the last
>     handler it caused to be executed. If no handlers are triggered, it
>     returns undefined

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue! I can't believe I missed that. :)